# Formatting milliseconds to date String WITHOUT SimpleDateFormatter (which produces garbage)

Tags: java

I am looking for a Java implementation of a date formatter from an epoch milliseconds long. I do NOT want to use SimpleDateFormatter because it produces garbage to the GC. I am looking for a fast and garbage-free Java implementation. Has anyone seen that somewhere?

```
StringBuilder sb = getReusableStringBuilder();

parse(sb, System.currentTimeMillis());
```

EDIT: That's for a logging library so it must include the time as well.

Comment: If you don't want to produce garbage, don't use a garbage-collected language. Why do you care about the garbage produced by SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: @JB Nizet: I don't have this option. I have to use Java and I have to minimize the GC latency. This is not an uncommon requirement for low-latency industries.

Comment: @JB Nizet, If less than 1% of your application needs to be GC-less would you change the other 99% just to fit this requirement?

Comment: If avoiding garbage is your goal then why are you turning perfectly valid `long` valid into unhandly (and probably avoidable) `String` objects in the first place?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: I edited my question. That is for a logging library.

Comment: Have you checked **how much** garbage `SimpleDateFormat` produces? Specifically if you use the [`format(Date, StringBuffer, FieldPosition)` variant](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date,%20java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.text.FieldPosition))? Because I expect it to be *very little*.

Comment: Logs as usually text, but they can be binary. (You would need to write a log reader)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: if 99% of the app is not GC-less, then the remaining 1% is also not GC-less, since the GC could run while executing the 1% code.

Comment: @Joachim Saucer, Creating the String uses twice the memory as calling format this way. ;)

Comment: @JB Nizet, most applications spend most of their time in a small percentage of code.  You can take the view that it all has to be super fast and you put maximum effort into all the code, or you can take the view that it doesn't matter what most of the code does provided it doesn't show up in the profiler and only optimise the critical path of your system. For me its a question of what is most productive.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: that's my point. It looks like premature optimization. Either the log level is set to TRACE, and the logging code will be executed very often, but the calling code will generate much more garbage than the logging library itself (all the strings that must be logged, for example), or it's set to ERROR, and generating some garbage won't do any harm, because it won't be called often.

Comment: @JB Nizet, I agree with your examples, however some log are INFO level, which cannot be turned off, but common enough to be a problem.

Comment: @Joachim: The variant format(Date, StringBuilder, FieldPosition) creates garbage. My goal is to create zero garbage. :)

Comment: @Sergio: Then I'd argue that this is not a worthy goal in a language such as Java. Producing little garbage or not producing easily avoidable garbage or keeping GC-induced latency below some threshold are worthy goals. "Create zero garbage" is right up there with "my code must be as fast as possible" and "the code must be bug-free".

Comment: @Joachim: I must agree with you. There is Real-time Java VM for example. However that can be done with Java. I agree it is not easy, but it can be done and for a logging library I believe it is worth investing to make it garbage-free. Also if you are after that goal of low garbage, you must be ready to bootstrap the Java libraries.

Comment: Creating a `String` that you then throw away is guaranteed to create garbage.

Comment: @Raedwald: I will never do this. You can get the contents out of a StringBuilder without creating a String.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was much simpler than I thought: bootstrap FieldPosition so it does not leak memory.

Comment: Since nobody directed me to a code that implemented the formatting logic, I am going to choose this answer if nothing else comes up.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a background logger which records time/dates and a StringBuilder to log entirely in the background. The typical latency is below one micro-second per call. It recycles everything so no GC is produced.

This is much more efficient than using a queue to pass work between two threads. All the queue implementations create garbage unfortunately. :(

```
import java.util.concurrent.Exchanger;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

class BackgroundLogger implements Runnable {
  static final int ENTRIES = 64;

  static class LogEntry {
    long time;
    int level;
    final StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
  }

  static class LogEntries {
    final LogEntry[] lines = new LogEntry[ENTRIES];
    int used = 0;
  }

  private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
  final Exchanger<LogEntries> logEntriesExchanger = new Exchanger<LogEntries>();
  LogEntries entries = new LogEntries();

  BackgroundLogger() {
    executor.submit(this);
  }

  // put whatever you want in the StringBuilder, before the next call!
  public StringBuilder log(int level) {
    try {
      if (entries.used == ENTRIES)
        entries = logEntriesExchanger.exchange(entries);
      LogEntry le = entries.lines[entries.used++];
      le.time = System.currentTimeMillis();
      le.level = level;
      return le.text;

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  public void flush() throws InterruptedException {
    entries = logEntriesExchanger.exchange(entries);
    entries = logEntriesExchanger.exchange(entries);
  }

  public void stop() {
    try {
      flush();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    executor.shutdownNow();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    LogEntries entries = new LogEntries();
    try {
      while(!Thread.interrupted()) {
        entries = logEntriesExchanger.exchange(entries);
        for (int i = 0; i < entries.used; i++) {
          bgLog(entries.lines[i]);
          entries.lines[i].text.delete(0, entries.lines[i].text.length());
        }
        entries.used = 0;
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {

    } finally {
      System.out.println("logger stopping.");
    }
  }

  private void bgLog(LogEntry line) {
    // log the entry to a file.
  }
}
```

---

I have written one.

If you allow a little bit of garbage you can simplify your problem.  You can use SimpleDateFormatter to format the date each time it changes (i.e. once per day) and produce the time and seconds using division.

Note: by creating a String you are still producing garbage (a String, and a char[] even if you don't use a StringBuilder which is tricky).

I would append to a recycled ByteBuffer to avoid any GC. (except at around midnight)

---

As @Joachim Saucer suggests the formatter can be used to produce less garbage.  I suspect that unless you also drop the production of a String, its not going to make much difference.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
Date tmpDate = new Date();
final FieldPosition pos = new FieldPosition(0);
{
  long free1 = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    tmpDate.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    sdf.format(tmpDate, sb, pos);
    sb.delete(0, sb.length());
  }
  long free2 = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
  if (free1 == free2) throw new Error("This must be run with -XX:-UseTLAB");
  System.out.println("SDF.format used an average of " + (free1 - free2) / 1000 + " bytes");
}
{
  long free1 = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    tmpDate.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    sdf.format(tmpDate, sb, pos);
    String str = sb.toString();
    sb.delete(0, sb.length());
  }
  long free2 = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
  if (free1 == free2) throw new Error("This must be run with -XX:-UseTLAB");
  System.out.println("SDF.format with a String used an average of " + (free1 - free2) / 1000 + " bytes");
}
```

prints

```
SDF.format used an average of 24 bytes
SDF.format with a String used an average of 120 bytes
```

Comment: I would use a StringBuilder not to produce Strings, so the formatting logic would write to a StringBuilder. I am changing my question to make that clear.

Comment: Your approach is cool, Peter. I would not mind caching the date and calculating only the time on each log. But time logic can be a pain, specially with daytime savings, timezone, etc. Before starting to code something myself, I want to take some time to see if I can find something already done out there.

Comment: Reusing the `FieldPosition` reduces the average memory use to just 24 bytes (another 32 bytes fewer!). And it's probably save, since you already share the `SimpleDateFormat` and the `StringBuffer`, so it needs to be synchronized in some way anyway.

Comment: @Peter: very cool way of measuring the memory use and I didn't know of `UseTLAB`. I'd *really* like to +1 this answer more than once.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer, Thank you. I should have spotted that.

Comment: So by using -XX:-UseTLAB the GC will not kick in in the middle of your benchmark?

Comment: The TLAB is an allocation of a block of memory in each thread for efficient multi-threaded memory allocation. Unused portions of these blocks don't count to the free space. Turning them off gives much more predictable answers to the size of objects. You can see the smallest object make a difference.

Comment: The TLAB can explain why creating lots of threads uses up the heap very quickly.  This is because it allocates a large chunk as soon as the thread is started. (Which is only recycled on a GC)

Comment: @Peter: ok, but if the GC decides to kick in in the middle of your benchmark, the results will be incorrect, right? There should be a way in Java to turn off GC, at least for debugging/testing, but there is not. :-(

Comment: @Sergio Oliveira Jr. Creating a few thousand objects is unlikely to trigger a GC anyway (I am assuming here)

Comment: If your eden size is large enough and has enough free space it won't trigger a GC. (With the exception of running out of Direct memory, ConcMarkSweep deciding now is a good time, the DGC+RMI, allocating large blocks of memory and filling the tenured space) But apart from all that you can be sure a GC won't run. ;)

Comment: try this test with `-verbosegc -XX:NewSize=1g -XX:SurvivorRatio=20` You won't see any GC even on startup. I would run your test with an 8 GB Eden space and see how you go. ;)

Comment: Here is an example of what a low garbage system looks like http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-avoid-garbage-collection.html There is only one GC per day (at 5 am) It is running in Apache Karaf with iPOJO and ActiveMQ which gives you all the nice features of OSGI and JMS but has no impact from GC (because there aren't any)

Comment: @Peter: Cool, i guess you can use -verbosegc to make sure the GC did NOT kick in and spoil my results. I ran the benchmark myself and it is a fact that even the variant format(Date, StringBuilder, FieldPosition) creates garbage. My goal is to create ZERO garbage. :)

Comment: @Sergio Oliveira Jr., You could use a `ThreadLocal<StringBuilder>` for logging.

Comment: @Peter: I am not creating any Strings, I am using a StringBuilder. The culprit is the SimpleDateFormat. Now my goal is to code a formatter that produces ZERO garbage. :)

Comment: @Sergio Oliveira Jr. The other reason I used a ByteBuffer was to avoid garbage created by the character encoder. (Or the overhead of converting char to byte) I assumed all my logs were ASCII.

Comment: @Peter: Good point about ByteBuffer. However I am more paranoid about GC (and its stop-the-world latency) than I am with speed. Of course I am with speed as well, but on a microsecond level. I would think you are saving nanoseconds here by using a ByteBuffer, but I did not measure. :)

Comment: Lots of other things are more important; like how you asynchronously write to disk or a socket and how you batch your logs.

Comment: @Peter: The only extra thread I would want to have on my system (besides of course the ones the VM creates) is logging, for asynchronous logging. I don't want DISK I/O latency blocking my main thread.

Comment: I suggest you look at the Exchanger class which works very well for this sort of thing. You might be able to pass encoding the date/time to the logging thread as well. ;)

Comment: Hey Peter. Your code is cool, but where does the date formatting take place?

Comment: The time is recorded in the producer thread but converted in the consumer thread. Even if you are caching the date, the time with lots of `/` and `%` takes a few micro-seconds each ;)

Comment: BTW I used a microsecond timer as well. i.e. the number of micro-second since the start of the day.

Answer (score 0):

I created the library with DateTimes utility class for this purpose. Internally it takes the "long value" of milliseconds since 1970/01/01 00:00:00.000 and calculates the year, month, day, hour, minute, second and millisecond values. Then it puts this info as an ASCII string into provided byte array, no new objects for GC. This byte array can be printed to console with System.out.write() method without creating a new String object.

You can get the library as jar file from my website [here](http://alexapps.net/Articles/Java/TimeFormatter/index.xhtml). Article describes the usage and compares the performance.

Answer (score -3):

Always use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) when you need to handle anything date and time related. It also contains formatters.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain how to use it so it produces minimal GC.